How to use Nginx to replace a Python Flask application which provides an endpoint to download a single static file
Some time ago I wrote a small Python application using Flask to provide a webserver which would allow users to download a single static file over the internet.
It looked something like this:
import flask

app = flask.Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return 'go to /file.txt to download file'

@app.route('/file.txt')
def file_txt():
    
    with open('/static/file.txt', 'r') as ifile:
    
        data = ifile.read()
        return data

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, host='127.0.0.1', port=80)

I now want to do something similar, however instead of serving a small file, I want to serve a much larger file, containing about 15 GB of data. This is large enough that it does not fit in the 4 GB RAM, $5/mo Linode server on which it needs to run.
Rather than figure out how to read the file in chunks and provide a way to download this with flask, it occured to me that one of the primary use cases for Nginx is to serve static files, so rather than hacking together a Python app to do this, why not use a tool which was designed for it?
I don't understand how to program the configuration files to make it do this. I have installed it, and I have a domain name set up to point to the ipv4 address of the Linode server.
The file I want to provide users a way to download is at /static/file.txt.
Here's the config I have tried:
# cat nginx.conf
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
        worker_connections 768;
        # multi_accept on;
}

http {

        sendfile on;
        tcp_nopush on;
        types_hash_max_size 2048;
        # server_tokens off;

        # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
        # server_name_in_redirect off;

        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        default_type application/octet-stream;

        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;

        gzip on;

        # gzip_vary on;
        # gzip_proxied any;
        # gzip_comp_level 6;
        # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
        # gzip_http_version 1.1;
        # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

        server {
                listen 80;
                listen [::]:80;
                server_name my-server-domain-name.example;

                location /download/ {
                        root /static;

                        add_header X-debug-message "test" always;

                        try_files /file.txt =404;
                }
        }

        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
        include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}

There are no symbolic links in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled.

This question is similar to: How do I serve a specific file on my server as a specific path with nginx?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

The location block has a syntax error - a trailing /.
It should be location /download not location /download/.
location /download {
    root /static;

    add_header X-debug-message "test" always;

    try_files /file.txt =404;
}

Now, it works.
